# How to install org-mode 8.3.2

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have latest stable Emacs version (GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32)) and try install org-mode 8.3.2.

I read http://orgmode.org/ and do

```
M-x list-packages RET
```

and install org-mode and org-plus-contrib

After instalation I have older version org-mode:

> Org-mode version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @
>   c:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20151005/)

How can I install org-mode 8.3.2.

Thank in advance

Krzysiek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution

Move

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
```

from the bottom to the top .emacs.

Answer (score 1):

When updating org-mode, I start emacs with the `-q` switch, then install the new version with `M-x package`

I'm not sure if it's still the case, but in the past you had to completely unload org-mode prior to installing a new version.